Is the solution of the dual problem feasible?
Thank you for reading my question.
Assume we have a problem,
$$
\begin{align}
&\min_x f_0(x)\\
s.t.\quad &h_i(x)=0, i= 1,\dots, p\\
&f_i(x)\leq 0, i =1,\dots,m
\end{align}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\min_{x}\max_{\nu,\lambda\geq 0}f_0(x)+\sum_{i=1}^pv_ih_i(x)+\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_if_i(x)
$$
And the dual is
$$
\max_{\nu,\lambda\geq 0}\min_{x}f_0(x)+\sum_{i=1}^pv_ih_i(x)+\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_if_i(x)
$$
If the dual has a solution, is it true that the corresponding $x$ is always feasible? i.e. $h_i(x)=0, f_i(x)\leq 0$.
If not, could you give me a counter example?
Thank you! Any help is appreciated.
